# unpack a malware manually

Tags: ollydbg, malware, unpacking

I`m working on this malware to analyze:

```
http://www.freeuploadsite.com/do.php?id=74209
password: infected
```

It seems it is packed but when I use "PE View" , etc tools to find the packer, their results are nothing.

How can I unpack this malware manually?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried PEiD or Protection ID? If you know what packer it is your job becomes much easier.